# ZSH ranges with variables

Tags: zsh

I've got a directory containing a few files whose filenames looks like this:

```
$ print *.log
20131010.log 20131011.log 20131012.log 20131013.log 20131014.log 20131015.log 20131016.log 20131017.log 20131018.log 20131019.log 20131020.log 20131021.log 20131022.log
```

If I only want the files before a given date, I could do:

```
$ print <-20131015>.log
20131010.log 20131011.log 20131012.log 20131013.log 20131014.log 20131015.log
```

What I'd like to do is something similar to this:

```
$ d=20131015
$ print <-$d>.log
zsh: no such file or directory: -20131015
```

What is the proper solution to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sub-shell. There may be a prettier way but this gets the job done:

```
d=20131015
print `zsh -c "ls <-$d>.log"`
```

**EDIT:**
Maybe `echo` would be better than `ls` there.